# React Native: Tried to register two views with the same name GestureHandlerRootView

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have installed and I am using @rainbow-me/animated-charts, @gorhom/bottom-sheet@^4, and follow the steps and I have yarn add react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler. This is my package.json

```json
"main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4",
    "@rainbow-me/animated-charts": "^1.0.0-alpha.6",
    "expo": "~45.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.3.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.2.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.8.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: I meant I follow the steps from gorhom's website:  https://gorhom.github.io/react-native-bottom-sheet/

Comment: have you restarted metro since you installed? `npx react-native start --reset-cache`

Comment: I am using expo so I used expo r -c